# ASM to push function arguments to the stack

Tags: visual-c++, assembly, 64-bit, push, inline-assembly

I'm trying to port a program to x64 using vs2008. The problem is, however, that the is some inline asm code that is not supported on x64. This asm code is used to push arguments with unknown type or number to functions from dll. It is an interpeter based program in which you can specify a function to use from a certain dll and the program pushes the arguments and calles the function at compile time.

Using various sources I've concluded that generating seperate .asm files that contain asm functions which can be compiled unsing masm and their obj files linked to vs2008. Using different files for x86 and x64 the program builds for both problems. The problem is however, that the functions do not replicate what the inline asm is doing.

I converted the following inline code, for example:

```
double a = Evaluate(arg[i]).num;
_asm  push a  + 4 
_asm  push a
j += 8;
```

To:

```
double a = Evaluate(arg[i]).num;
EvaluateFuncArgFloat(a);
j += 8;
```

With the follwoing .asm file:

```
TITLE EvaluateFuncArgFloat                      (evaluate_asm.asm)

.386
.model flat, C

.code
EvaluateFuncArgFloat PROC a:DWORD

        push    a + 4
        push    a
        ret

EvaluateFuncArgFloat ENDP

END
```

This does not do what I'm expecting. The double simply does not end up in the function as it did when using inline asm.

My guess is that there is a small error or something I've left out, but after many tries I can't seem to get it to work. Hopefully someone can help me with this problem, it is very much appriciated.

Comment: Calling a function can't have the same semantics as your inline assembly... there's a function call involved, and that will modify the stack.

Comment: What happens after this code? Function arguments might be expected to be found in registers rather than on the stack on x86-64.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. Michael: After this code it calls the function using the interpreted name and this declaration: double (*func_d)(void);

Comment: Thanks Carl, I was thinking that might cause the problem. Can you think of any workarounds, or other approaches?

Comment: Are you not getting your stack muddled up? Two pushes and a ret means it rets to the second push

Comment: @user2486757: You might want to take a look at the [calling conventions for x86-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_x64_calling_convention).

Comment: Thanks Ady, that maybe. I did try many variants, do you have any suggestions? I do not have much asm experience by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the link Michael. I did not menition it explicitly, but I'm still stuck on trying the get it to work for 32 bit. Hopelfully I can use you link when get 32 bit to work as it did.

Comment: @user2486757: Oh, you're still on the 32-bit code. Well, to get your assembly function to return to the correct place you could try changing it to something like: `pop eax` / `push dword ptr [a+4]` / `push dword ptr [a]` / `push eax` / `ret`.

Comment: Thanks Michael. That did the trick (after correcting some other errors that slipped in while trying so hard). I'll clean some more and try to increase my understanding of this. Then on to x64. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sneaky way to do this could be

```
 EvaluateFuncArgFloat PROC a:DWORD

    pop eax            ;ret address popped to a safe register (if not ax/eax)
    push    a + 4
    push    a
    push eax           ;ret address back at top of stack
    ret

 EvaluateFuncArgFloat ENDP
```

The problem is you've pushed 2 numbers onto the stack and not removed them a+4 and a

Presumably another part of your original code deals with this in the original program

Comment: Thanks Ady! I used the code commented by Michael above. It included dword ptr's, which worked very well. You added comment is also correct, later on in de code the stack is restored.